# Updating UI when a model property changes in an ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, mvvm-light

I have a view that has a group of images I get from a web service
I receive them in a list of this class:

```
 public class ImageModel 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string imageUrl { get; set; }
    }
```

under each image I show an up-vote button, so I added another bool property to the model above:

```
 public bool UpVoted { get; set; }
```

the `ListView` that shows these images is bound to an `ObservableCollection<ImageModel >` , I want to change the voting icon through a converter that convert the value of `UpVoted` to the corresponding icon, when the user click the voting icon: a command execute this method:

```
    private void OnVoting(ImageModel image)
    {
        Images.Single(x => x.id == image.id).UpVoted = !image.UpVoted;
    }
```

the problem is that the UI is not updated, and to make sure that I understood the problem I turned the model to a View model and made the required changes to the `UpVoted` property (I'm using MVVM light library)

```
bool upVoted;
        public bool UpVoted
        {
            get { return upVoted; }
            set
            {
                Set(ref upVoted, value);
            }
        }
```

and it works now, 
so I need to bind the `UpVoted` to the UI, so it's updated whenever it changed

Comment: What's the issue here?  As far as I can see you've just explained how MVVM works.

Comment: Having the list of ImageModels observable will only notify if an entry to that list is added or removed. If you want the model to notify about changes to one of its properties you have to do it there or use a ViewModel as you did. I would just have the ViewModel reference the Property of the Model if you want to store it or something like that.

Comment: To complement what @Fildor said, one of the solutions (at least in UWP) is to subscribe when you add items in your list by settings it's PropertyChanged event handler to a method which will notify your ObservableCollection that an item has been modified, and the opposite when your item has been removed from the collection.

Comment: @Fildor can you please elaborate more a bit on this:
"I would just have the ViewModel reference the Property of the Model if you want to store it or something like that".. how to achieve that?

Comment: I just referred to " I turned the model to a View model" - I'd have both. So you can separate Concerns. The model holds the data, the ViewModel prepares them for the view. So you can keep your Model as is and the viewmodel cares about raising change notifications.

Comment: If I created a new View model.. it's only job will be implementing INPC for only one property, it will also not handling any other tasks done usually by view models?

Answer (score 2):

first 
your model class must inherit from MvxNotifyPropertyChanged

```
public class ImageModel : MvxNotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        private bool upVoted ;
        public bool UpVoted 
        {
            get { return upVoted ; }
            set { upVoted = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => UpVoted ); }
        }
    }
```

then with `MvxValueConverter`  you ready to go

Comment: Yes, so abstractly spoken: observable collection does not update the view when a property on one of its elements changes. the elements have to do this on their own. (or the collection subscribes to the propertychanged events on its elements, but i do not recommend said implementation)

Comment: I opted in the INPC, but curious to know where's `MvxNotifyPropertyChanged` ?

Comment: @mshwf - NOTE: `MvxNotifyPropertyChanged` is specific to `MvvmCross` library. `INotifyPropertyChanged` is the interface all `BindableObject`s support, so if using a different MVVM library, look for a base class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. For example, in `TinyMvvm`, the class to inherit from is `TinyMvvm.ViewModelBase`. If you inherit `INotifyPropertyChanged` directly, then you'll need to implement the needed members yourself. I'll add an answer showing that.

Answer (score 1):

Mustafa's answer mentions a class that is specific to MvvmCross library.
Another alternative is `TinyMvvm`.

If you wish to write your own MVVM (or understand how MVVM works),
the general pattern is to implement INotifyPropertyChanged: [Implement Property Change Notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification), which [I discuss here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50434220/199364).

A convenient way to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, is to make a base class that does that implementation, then inherit from that base class. You can use the code in that sample as your base class. Or use a slightly different implementation, that avoids having to manually pass the property name as a string:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

// Use this as base class for all your "view model" classes.
// And possibly for your (domain) model classes.
// E.g.:  "public class MyLoginViewModel : HasNotifyPropertyChanged".
// OR     "public class MyLoginModel : HasNotifyPropertyChanged".
// Give it whatever name you want, for ViewModels I suggest "ViewModelBase".
public class HasNotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // --- This is pattern to use to implement each property. ---
    //     This works for any property type: int, Color, etc.
    //     What's different from a standard c# property, is the "SetProperty" call.
    //     You will often write an IValueConverter (elsewhere) to use in XAML to convert from string to your property type,
    //     or from your property type to a type needed in your UI.
    //     Comment out this example property if you don't need it.
    /// <summary>
    /// Set to "true" at end of your initialization.
    /// Then can use Property Trigger on Ready value=true in XAML to do something when your instance is ready for use.
    /// For example, load something from web, then trigger to update UI.
    /// </summary>
    private bool _ready;
    public bool Ready
    {
        get => _ready;
        set => SetProperty(ref _ready, value);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void SetProperty<T>(ref T property, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (property == null || !property.Equals(value))
        {
            property = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Again, an alternative to the above code is to use an existing MVVM library.

For another alternative, **that doesn't require writing "SetProperty(..)" or "OnPropertyChanged(..)" in all of your property setters**, google for info about using [**Fody/PropertyChanged**](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged). Then you wouldn't need any of the above code; your class would simply inherit from `INotifyPropertyChanged`. (And in app startup, you call a method that "injects" the needed logic into all properties of all INotifyPropertyChanged classes.)

Acknowledgement:  The code pattern in example above is based on one of the open source libraries. It might be from TinyMvvm.

Answer (score 0):

you do not say which sort of container that you are using but not all controls are set to support two way notification by default. so you may have to add a

```
Mode=TwoWay
```

to get notifications from the back end that data has changed. Or as the previous answer by Mustafa indicated you may need to verify that your class is implementing the InotifyPropertyChanged event with mvvm light.